# Async methods with threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio

I have a method that launches a new std::thread for new connections so that I can read data and do other things.
The method the thread invokes runs the reads in an asynchronous way(using boost functions) and it returns once it calls `async_read_some`, my question is:

What thread handles the call-back?  Is it the same thread that made the call to the `async_read_some` or did that thread die after it called it and returned and now the main thread is handling the reads?

Here's a code snippet:

```
    connection::connection_thread = std::thread(&connection::read_header,
                                                 this);
    connection::connection_thread.detach();
               .
               .
               .
  void connection::read_header() {
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(headbuf_),
      strand_.wrap(
        boost::bind(&connection::on_header_read, shared_from_this(),
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)));
    begin_timeout();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What thread handles the call-back?

The thread (or one of the threads, if there are more than one) which polls or runs the associated [`io_service`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html). The handler is passed to the service to be called on completion.

> Is is the same thread that made the call to the async_read_some

No, the `async` functions never call the handler directly; it is always called by the `io_service`, even if the operation completes immediately.

> or did that thread die after it called it and returned and now the main thread is handling the reads?

That entirely depends on how you're managing the threads. The thread that calls `async` may die, if you don't need it any more; you'll need some other thread or threads (possibly the main thread, possibly others) to process the `io_service` and complete the asynchronous operation.

However, there's no point launching a thread to start an asynchronous operation, since that will complete immediately. Either move the call to `async_read_some` to where you're currently launching the thread; or use the thread to perform a *synchronous* operation. If you opt for a multithreaded synchronous design, then you won't need a thread to poll the `io_service` for asynchronous operations.

Comment: I am not sure I got what you mean, sorry. The only thing I am doing with my thread is that I am creating a new one for every new connection, I then, using the newely created thread, call async_read_some and then the thread returns; nothing more.

Comment: @AdelQodmani: OK. You'll also need some thread to call `run` or `poll` on the `io_service`, in order to process the asynchronous operations; otherwise, they'll never happen (or at least, they'll never complete).

Comment: @AdelQodmani: There's no point launching a thread to start an asynchronous operation; the whole point is that you can start the operation *without* blocking the thread that does it. Either switch to synchronous operations (blocking the thread you've launched); or start the asynchronous operation *instead* of launching the thread.

Comment: I see, and if I go with asynchronous calls, would they internally launch threads of their own to perform the blocking-calls? or would this happen in the context of the caller-thread? or that depends on what I specify(if any, please let me know where I can specify such a thing)

Comment: @AdelQodmani: No, the asyncronous calls post requests to the `io_service`. To process them, you'll need one or more threads polling or running that. All the completion handlers will be executed on one of those threads.